# System is running in low-graphics mode after instaling Bumblebee in my Lenovo Z570 NVIDIA gpu

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, bumblebee

I am a newable ubuntu user about a month ago.

My machine's specs are:

```
Linux lenovo-Ideapad-Z570 3.11.0-19-generic #33~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 12 21:16:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm using

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

After a lot of experiments to my vga card to reduce the brightness of my screen I saw [a link for bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)  and I realized that I can fix my laptop's energy problem also.
But after the installation my ubuntu the only thing that give me is a **`system running in low-graphic mode`**.

After a lot of research I found the way to login in low res by getting in recovery menu, failsafeX, Reconf graphics, reboot and resume.

So what I have now is that my laptop can recognize the 
`VESA:Intel®Sandybridge Mobile Graphics` and not my NVIDIA GPU.

So I went to system settings -> Additional drivers and install the driver that was recommended. Reboot, but the same thing. The driver was active but not in use!!!!

So after this I've done `sudo fgrep nvidia * | fgrep blacklist`
and I found that my NVIDIA was blacklisted!!!

I uninstalled bumblebee

```
$ sudo apt-get remove bumblebee
$ sudo rm bumblebee.conf
```

and install again Nvidia drivers but nothing again

I've tried to do this

```
etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
```

But I had a `command not found`.

So I have only this now:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

I can't understand why Nvidia is blacklisted and why if I reinstall drivers it doesn't work.

Something more is that in bios there are only two options:

1. optimus = NVIDIA + INEL
2. UMA = Intel only

nothing works.

Is there any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best help, but I'm experiencing a lot of problems trying to install nvidia drivers for my GT740M. While Geforce.com informs to us that driver 331.20 supports GT740M, by executing "grep -FN 'NVRM:' /var/log/kern.log", I can see:

52044:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:0a:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1292)
52045:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: ***Installed in this system is not supported by the 331.20***
52046:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: NVIDIA Linux driver release.  Please see 'Appendix
52047:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's
52048:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: README, available on the Linux driver download page
52049:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.758568] NVRM: at www.nvidia.com.
52051:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.759140] NVRM: ***The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).***
52052:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.759143] NVRM: ***None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!***
52054:Apr 11 13:24:13 NAUTILUS kernel: [ 3270.759222] NVRM: NVIDIA init module failed!

Also, their 331.67 driver does not recognise my GPU (supposedly compatible with this driver, too!). I wrote to geforce.com commenting my problems. We'll see.

my original post, commands used, etc, in:

[Ubuntu 12.04 Bumblebee vs Nvidia GeForce GT 740M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446581/ubuntu-12-04-bumblebee-vs-nvidia-geforce-gt-740m)

Best wishes! and Good Luck!